# Binding dose not seem to be working from ReactiveCocoa Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

```
var viewModel = CTCViewModel()
var mainView: CTCMainView {
    return self.view as! CTCMainView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let callButtonEnabledSignal = self.viewModel.rac_valuesForKeyPath("callButtonEnabled", observer: self.viewModel)
    callButtonEnabledSignal.setKeyPath("enabled", onObject: self.mainView.callButton, nilValue: false)

    self.mainView.callButton.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside).subscribeNext {
        (Void) -> Void in
        self.viewModel.callButtonEnabled = !self.viewModel.callButtonEnabled
    }
}
```

When I press the button, `self.viewModel.callButtonEnabled` did get updated but the `enabled` property of the button. It does not seem they are bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `dynamic` on your `callButtonEnabled` property:

```
class CTCViewModel: NSObject {
    dynamic var callButtonEnabled = false
}
```

Because the implementation of `rac_valuesForKeyPath` is using Objective-C runtime, and the compiler can omit it when access Swift properties. You mark a property with `dynamic` to let the compiler always use Objective-C runtime.